# How to show an notification using tonyodev.fetch2

Tags: android, android-download-manager, fetch2

We are developing an app in Android Studio that download multiple files using [Fetch2](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch).
Currently we already can download files, but we want to show the user feedback about the progress by using a notification. A download can contain multiple files. If that’s the case, the notification should only show the total progress of the queue, not the files separately. We are using a manager class to handle the downloads across or app.

Here is a copy of my current [downloadManager][2]:

https://pastbin.com/KmM0S9qH

I try to use this as a reference, but the notification simple won’t show up:
https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch/issues/276

In short, how can I show a notification about the download progress using Fetch2 api?

Your help is much appreciated since there not a wide community for this api.